# Scrollview doesnt work with framelayout

Tags: android

I have an activity layout that includes my fragment container this way,

```
<include
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/background_container" />
```

and my fragment container is compose of linearlayout and a framelayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:padding="10dp">

   <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I have to add my scrollable fragment in this container but the scroll doesnt seem to work. My layout goes like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         ...

         ...

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have tried several answer like

1. Using NestedScrollView
2. Adding minimum height to framelayout
3. Using fillViewport="true"
4. etc.

But nothing seems to work. Any idea what I've been doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance! Cheers!

**Edit:**

My activity layout contains navigation drawer, i dont know if it matter. And i add the view using

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).commit();
```

i also dont know if fragment replace messes with my view. Please help. Thanks

Comment: android:layout_height="match_parent" for framelayout in your container.

Comment: @RajSuvariya i have done that, nothing. Thanks

Comment: @pskink im not familiar with that, can you enlighten me or give links about what you mean? thanks

Answer (score 2):

it seems my fragment container's LinearLayout is missing orientation and also frameLayout 
android:layout_height should be match_parent

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:orientation="vertical"  // orientation
  android:padding="10dp">

    <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" // match_parent
         android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nothing.. i had also tried changing that linear to scrollview and nestedscrollview but still nothing. thanks

Comment: @pskink im reading and still trying to understand it.. I get `adb is not recognize as command`